# Updating to Newest Version of Sylius

Tags: sylius

Looking at the recent changes to Sylius and the new interface, as well as the Roadmap which has beta 1.0 out in November, I'd love to update my development project to the newest version, and continue updating until the beta in November, at which point I'll stop and use this as the version which I finish development on. I see an old post here on SO about updating Sylius, but it's from 2014 and almost every package referenced is out of date. I'm looking for a fresh copy of a recent composer.json requirements list, or instructions on the easiest way to get my project up to date (without a total reinstall) so I can keep up until Beta 1.0. I'll attach my current composer.json require list, in case it's pertinant. Thanks!

```
"require": {
    "php": "^5.6|^7.0",
    "ext-exif": "*",
    "ext-fileinfo": "*",
    "ext-gd": "*",
    "doctrine/collections": "~1.2",
    "doctrine/common": "~2.5",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "~1.1.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "~1.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "~2.2",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "~1.0",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8,<2.5",
    "doctrine/phpcr-odm": "^1.3",
    "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle": "~1.4",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "~1.5",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.2",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.4.12",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "jackalope/jackalope": "^1.1.4",
    "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "^1.1.2",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^0.13|^1.0",
    "jms/translation-bundle": "^1.1",
    "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle": "~0.1",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~1.1",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "~1.2",
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "~1.0",
    "ocramius/proxy-manager": "^1.0",
    "omnipay/omnipay": "~2.3",
    "payum/omnipay-bridge": "~1.0",
    "payum/payum": "~1.3",
    "payum/payum-bundle": "~2.1",
    "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "~1.1",
    "polishsymfonycommunity/symfony-mocker-container": "^1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "~5.0",
    "symfony-cmf/block-bundle": "~1.2",
    "symfony-cmf/content-bundle": "~1.2",
    "symfony-cmf/create-bundle": "~1.2",
    "symfony-cmf/media-bundle": "~1.2",
    "symfony-cmf/menu-bundle": "~1.2",
    "symfony-cmf/routing-bundle": "^1.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "~1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-intl-icu": "~1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "~1.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "^2.8",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "twig/twig": "~1.11",
    "webmozart/assert": "^1.0",
    "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "~1.0",
    "willdurand/hateoas-bundle": "^0.4|^1.0",
    "winzou/state-machine-bundle": "~0.2",
    "zendframework/zend-hydrator": "^1.0|^2.0",
    "zendframework/zend-stdlib": "^2.0|^3.0",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "^2.2",
    "payum/stripe": "^1.3"
```

Comment: Without doing a complete reload it's incredibly fiddly trying to get everything updated. I tried to do it a couple of months ago and had to change a bunch of the code that i'd overridden as it now functions differently. Make sure if you're changing anything in the Sylius bundle that you do it as an override. Even then you will still have issues, but at least you can copy over the SyliusBundle folder

Comment: Helpful as always, thanks Brett! If you post this as an answer I'll accept. At some during the development cycle I'll update, but right now I won't risk it with a tight schedule.